# I want to use appcache in a local html static page

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I read about Appcache feature to cache files using cache manifest. I don't have any website hosted, instead i'm trying with a local html file. In this html file i'm referring to an online JS library which downloads from internet every time i open the page. To avoid this i'm trying cache manifest but it doesn't seem to work. Please tell me whether i can use it this way? If not is there any other approach? I cannot download JS library locally its the restriction i have.
I want the page to work offline from second time.

Thanks in advance
Manu

Html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
   <head>
       <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
       src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
       data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
       data-sap-ui-ibs='sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.ux3,sap.viz,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3'></script></head></html>


CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
#UI5 JS Files
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js
```

Cahce manifest is in a seperate file and stored in same location where html page is located.

Comment: Please post your code. What you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your local HTML page from a web server to be able to set the correct mime type for the manifest. Otherwise your app cache will never work.

But! You can't cache files from another host so your approach won't work anyway.

Are you trying to create an offline UI5 app? Then you should really take control of all relevant files on your own domain. If not, just rely on the browser cache for static javascript files. It's sufficient in 99% of all cases.

Comment: No i'm not trying to develop offline app. I want the page to work in case of no net connectivity.

Comment: That's the same thing as an offline app. You should host all files on a domain you control yourself.

Comment: I have a very valid use case for this scenario: I want to provide a nice software interface to search through and serve up a bunch of PDF files either from the server or from the local file system if the user has checked out the same SVN as I have.

Comment: With PDFs you will most likely run into the size limit of the app cache. The app cache would be a bad design choice.